# "Findstr" command to variable & File count w/ Subdirectories

Tags: batch-file

I was wondering if you can find a string using the "findstr" command and put it's results to a variable. it would also display what file path the found string is.
I did this to list files & it's subdirectories.

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%P IN ('dir /A-d /b') do echo %%P TO (PSEUDOCODE: TO tempres.rsm)
```

It only lists the FILES BUT NOT it's SUBDIRECTORIES.

What i would like it to do is the "For" command listed above to output to a variable
and a "findstr" command to output to another variable too.

HERES A FEW CODE /w PSEUDO IN IT

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%P IN ('dir /A-d /b') do echo %%P TO (PSEUDOCODE: TO tempres.rsm)
set /p searchinput="Search Term: "
findstr /f tempres.rsm /c %searchinput%
```

I would like it to notify the user if a string is FOUND or NOT found.

Thank you for your cooperation.

I'm still 11, by the way.

Comment: `dir` has a parameter `/s` which will include subdirectories

Comment: `findstr` expects the string in Quotations `"`

Comment: you can't combine the `/f` and `/c` parameter of findstr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `%found%` will be the last item, if there was more than one match from the search term.

```
@echo off
dir /a-d /b /s > "tempres.rsm"
set /p "searchinput=Search Term: "
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i /L /c:"%searchinput%" "tempres.rsm" ') do set "found=%%a"
echo "%found%"
del "tempres.rsm"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want, but

```
SET /P "searchinput=Search Term: "
FOR /R %%i IN (*.*) DO @(FINDSTR "%searchinput%" %%i >>tempres.rsm && ECHO %%i)
```

will store `findstr` results in `tempres.rsm` and display files for which string was found.

Comment: I wanted a dir count / file count w/ filenames to tempres.rsm and a findstr command to find a certain string E.G. FIle path and file name to find something. If found, You now know the file's location. IT's useful for file searching. foxidrive provided me with that so, I accepted his answer.